# Log out from kiosk mode?

Tags: logout, kiosk

Condition:
1 superuser, 1 kiosk-user.
Superuser has root access.
Kiosk-user we want to have access to only 2 apps, but not simultaneously.  2 gnome-desktops created for each app.

Scenario:
Kiosk-user logs in with selected desktop and app opens in full screen mode.  Kiosk-user closes app, script forces sleep for X then reopens app.  This is kiosk mode.

Desired affect:
Kiosk-user closes app which forces log out.  Then superuser has access or Kiosk-user chooses second gnome-desktop for app #2 in kiosk mode.

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure LightDM sessions by placing desktop files in /usr/share/xsessions.  For example, create file /usr/share/xsessions/app1.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Application 1
Exec=/path/to/app1
```

Likewise create file /usr/share/xsessions/app2.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Application 2
Exec=/path/to/app2
```

These are your two application sessions.

I assume your super-user would be using the normal Ubuntu desktop session.  I don't think you can configure LightDM to limit access to this session to the admin user, but you should be able to add an X session script that aborts the session startup if the kiosk user tries to access it. Try creating /etc/X11/Xsession.d/00-check-user with the following content:

```
if [ "$LOGNAME" = "kiosk" -a "$DESKTOP_SESSION" = "ubuntu" ]; then
    errormsg "user not allowed to access ubuntu session"
fi
```

You'll also want to remove unwanted sessions from /usr/share/xsessions as they may not run the full set of Xsession scripts and therefore could provide unwanted access to the kiosk user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above example is exactly how we have it setup.  However the issue is when kiosk-user closes the app it currently sleeps for 1s and restarts the app.  Keeping the user in kiosk mode.  This is fine if we are just allowing them access to 1 app.  But we have 2 we would like to use.  So the desired affect of closing the app would be to log the kiosk-user out completely.  This brings them back to a new session to log into app #2.

Comment: Are you using a script that restarts the app when it exits?  Normally you are taken back to the LightDM login screen when the application (the program in the Exec line) terminates.

Comment: hhhmmm  yes I am. while true; do app ; sleep 1s; done

Comment: If you remove the loop then you should return to the login screen after your app terminates. Then the user can select a different session if desired.